# Vim Regex: How do I match a literal "greater than" (">") / "less than" ("<") symbol?

Tags: regex, vim

Vim. Regex. How do I match this `>` and this `<`.

Comment: You match them directly.  It is confusing because with backslashes (`\<` and `\>`) they match word start/end, but without the backslashes they match themselves.

Comment: @ChrisDodd That is very confusing. It is also different to almost every other regex/language (I think)

Comment: @user3728501 read `:help pattern`. Vim has it’s own style of patterns. /shrug such is life.

Answer (score 4):

< and > are special regex characters that do not need to be escaped in vim (they need to be escaped to make them special) so you should be able to just do:

```
 :s/>/x/g
```

Answer (score 0):

To match this `>` AND this `<`, you can do `:%s/[<>]/x/g`

In that case, you would replace all `<` and `>` with "x."

If you want to search without replacing, you can just do `/[<>]` and then use `n` and `shift+n` to move forward and backward to each instance of the match.